# Zoom's "Follow Presenter's Pointer" only works sporadically

Tags: zoom.us

My company uses Zoom meetings daily with 5-30 attendees usually.  For attendees, the "Follow Presenter's Pointer" option is wildly inconsistent.  Sometimes it works as you would expect, other times it doesn't even appear as an option.  To be specific:

- User has their screensharing zoom level set to 100% (not "fit to screen").
- The option "Follow Presenter's Point" should appear.  Sometimes it does.  Often - around 1/3 of the time - it does not and there is absolutely no way to follow the presenter's cursor.
- Exiting/re-joining the meeting, does not reliably help.
- Logging out/back in to Zoom, does not reliably help.
- Rebooting, does not reliably help.

Basically I've not been able to find anything at all that will reliably, consistently, be guaranteed to return the Follow Presenter's Pointer functionality.

This causes a great deal of problems for our attendees, as we are sharing in 4k, and many people are on smaller screens, laptops, even mobile devices, and need to be able to be zoomed in to 100%, and have the cursor automatically followed.

I can't find anyone else referring to this online, yet we have dozens of people who experience this routinely.  Does anyone know why this happens, and how to solve it?

Comment: This should be a support request directed to Zoom.

Comment: Yeah they always just dismiss it as not being set to the right scale, not understanding their interface, etc.  Maybe I'll try again.

Comment: I get it. The intermittent nature of the problem combined with the variety of environments makes this more than a how do I use zoom.  Perhaps you need to upgrade to a paid tier, get this resolved, then downgrade.  If paying already they should see this through.

Comment: We're already on a paid tier though so... yeah.  =/